# Finding straight streets going from south to north using QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, expression, streets

How do I find straight streets going from south to north with an inclination of 5° maximum using QGIS.

Here is an example
[image]

The red line indicates the street I am looking for.

These streets are very common in the United States, but rare in Europe.

Comment: For which area would you like to find those streets? What have you tried by so far?

Answer (score 7):

You don't have included information about what data you have and the software you use, so this here is a demonstration using QGIS with OpenStreetMap (OSM) data, a selction of Kansas city. As both are open source/open data and OSM is available worldwide, there should not be any restrictions for using it.
However, the workflow should work in a similar fashion using other software/data. I used the following steps:

1. Download data with [QuickOSM](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) pluging with `key=highway` - you get a lines layer for the streets (delete points and polygons layer). Note: in the screenshot below, only streets in the upper part in the middle were downloaded, so only there you see results, for the rest of the map canvas I did not download any streets.
2. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Explode lines` to get single small lines for every section of the street (a road can have changing azimuth with curves)
3. Use the field calculator to create a new attribute with this expression that calculates the azimuth (inclination) in degrees for each line (street section):

   `degrees ( azimuth ( start_point ( $geometry ), end_point ( $geometry ) ) )`
4. Set a Rule based style or use select by expression whereas the rule/expression is `"azimuth" <=5 or ( "azimuth" >=175 and "azimuth" <=185) or "azimuth" >=355`.

You have to include the values with an azimuth +-5 degrees from 0 degrees (from 0 to 5 and 355 to 360: from -5 to 0, so to say) as well as the values around 180 degrees +- 5 to include both roads that run north-south as well as south-north. We used the expressions with start_point and end_point, so sometimes the start is in the northern end, sometimes in the southern end.

[image]